# Importing classes Java

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBJVr.png)I have problems with importing classes in my java projects. In the code java doesn`t want to add Scanner, even with import java.util.Scanner; statement.

```
public class Menu {
  public void menu() {
    java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a JRE/JDK installed? did you set the path of your IDE? You're providing way to little a context to be able to find the issue

Comment: What exactly is your problem?
Do you get a compile error?

Comment: No import statement is needed in this code, since the full package is used. The import statement would be necessary when you write only `Scanner`, not `java.util.Scanner`. Regardless, you problem is probably that you get an error. Describe the error.

Comment: `Scanner` class does not have default c-tor

Comment: I guess your IDE is telling you something along the lines `no suitable constructor found for Scanner(no arguments)`. You need to pass some arguments to the constructor. For example if you want to read input from console `= new Scanner(System.in)`

Comment: Adding parameter System.in is not working.

Comment: "is not working" is not an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which java version do you use? 
If I look at the scanner documentation, there are several constructors, but no default constructor. You need to pass some arguments for the call "new java.util.Scanner(xxxx)"

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html